# What is this jQuery syntax doing?

Tags: jquery

```
$(".topLevelCategoryContainer img").width($(this).parent().parent().width()).css({ "text-align": "center", "border": "none", "margin-left": "0" });
```

I'm not understanding the .width and .parent()'s.
Thanks.

Comment: It's setting the width of an image to the width of its parent's parent (among other CSS settings). See [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: Did you read the documentation about those methods on the jQuery website?

Answer (score 0):

```
// this gets images within the .topLevelCategoryContainer element
$(".topLevelCategoryContainer img")
    // this sets the width of the image
    .width(
        // this gets the value to set the width to, in this case
        // to the same width as the images parents parent
        $(this).parent().parent().width()
    )
    //this sets CSS on the image
    .css({ 
       "text-align": "center", 
       "border": "none", 
       "margin-left": "0" 
    });
```